# Why client can't acquire messages from server streaming?

Tags: python, grpc, freeze, http2, grpc-python

I have Python server and client in gRPC. After adding ClientInterceptor I can't receive messages from `unary_stream` method from the server on client side. On the server side I can see that stream is over, all messages has been sent.
It's like client is not aware that there are no messages left and there's no need to wait. Adding `wait_for_ready` didn't help, it just fails with the DEADLINE error. `stream_stream` method works fine.

Calling `response.code()` or `response.result()` results infinite wait time.

Calling `response.done()` returns `false`, `response.running()` returns true. My interceptor:

```
    def _intercept_stream_call(self, continuation, client_call_details, request_or_iterator):

        for try_i in range(self.max_attempts):
            response = continuation(client_call_details, request_or_iterator)

            if isinstance(response, _MultiThreadedRendezvous):
                if response.code() == grpc.StatusCode.CANCELLED:
                    if try_i == (self.max_attempts - 1):
                        return response
                    else:
                        self.sleeping_policy.sleep(try_i)
                else:
                    return list(response)


        def intercept_unary_stream(self, continuation, client_call_details, request):
            return self._intercept_stream_call(continuation, client_call_details, request)
```

Code freezes on line `if response.code() == grpc.StatusCode.CANCELLED:`. If I run that line in evaluator, same situation. The workaround is to call in evaluator `list(response)`. After that, `response.code()` will return the value.

Pls help to understand what am I doing wrong.

My server method:

```
def watchStream(self, request, context):
        for i in range(3):
            log.info(f'Returned response {i} to watch stream...')
            yield social_media_stream_pb2.StreamUpdate(audio_chunk=social_media_stream_pb2.AudioChunk(audio_data=f'Audio{i}'.encode()),
                                                       video_frame=social_media_stream_pb2.VideoFrame(frame_data=f'Video{i}'.encode()))
```

I've tried to run `list(response)` before running `response.code()` or `response.result()`. It helped, but I don't know why, it's just a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encountering a *deadlock* when calling `response.code()`. [From the docs](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.UnaryStreamClientInterceptor.intercept_unary_stream), the return value of `continuation` is

> an object that is both a Call for the RPC and a Future

That means that the object is guaranteed to fulfill these two interfaces:

- [`grpc.Call`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.Call)
- [`grpc.Future`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.Future)

The return value is *not* however, guaranteed to be a response message. This is because `continuation` returns not after the RPC response has been received, but instead immediately after the RPC has been *sent*. If you attempt to access the code on the RPC, the library will block waiting for your RPC to complete so that the code is set. But the library will not make progress on receiving the RPC because you've blocked the thread waiting on the code to be populated. Deadlock.

Instead, you should set up a *callback* to do something conditioned on the RPC status *only once the RPC response has been received*. The method to do this is [`add_done_callback`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.Future.add_done_callback)

P.S. Please don't reference `_MultiThreadedRendezvous` in your code. It's an internal API. You should be able to do everything without referencing it.

Comment: Thanks, @RichardBelleville, that makes sense. I've reworked my code, catch grpc error is enough